# Timing Issue with 4 Threads / 4 Processes in Parallel Programming

Tags: c, mpi, openmp, intel, linux-mint

I am having issues with OpenMP and MPI execution timings. When I select either 4 Threads (OMP) or 4 Proccesses (MPI) my execution time is slower than the serial code.

Both scripts have correct timings on other machines and both use the gettimeofday() function for timing. Below is a screen shot of both scripts being executed from 1-8 Threads/Procs:

[image]

RAM is not exceeding its limit and the disk is not busy during execution.The machine hosts an Intel i5 2500k (Stock not overclocked) and is running on Linux Mint 17 x64.

AS mentioned before, both programs produce the correct timings on other machines, so I think the issue has something to do with cpu affinity and the OS.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

EDIT 1:

When using the argument 'bind-to-core' on the MPI execution, runtime is significantly increased, but still much slower than serial:

[image]

Comment: what exactly does the program entail? data processing? It really depends since really if your program is saturated more threads wont benefit the performance and even incur overhead from context switches. it seems that after 3 threads/processes you incur more overhead than you gain. it is really weird that you have a spike at 4 but without seeing some code no one can probably help you.

Comment: There is no problem with overhead as on other machines I get a performance drop due to overhead after 4 threads/procs (with the best performance at the 1 Thread/Proc per core ratio. Both programs take in an image at the start, applies a blurring algorithm then outputs a new image at the end. The timing is only done on the algorithm so there is no overhead in timing due to I/O. I would paste code but I am unsure which parts to add due to the length of each script

Comment: how is the work divided? there might be a some weird side effect if the work is divided four ways. I cannot imagine that it really is a hardware issue. maybe try to run it a different linux version from USB live stick and retry on the same machine

Comment: In the MPI script, procs are put into a Cart grid dynamically so there is no issue there. In the OMP script. Parallelism is achieve via #pragma omp for loops, so the work would be divided up evenly (I have tried numerous chunk sizes to no avail also). Somthing interesting I did discover was - if I supply the argument -bind-to-cpu on the mpi script, the timing for 4 procs is still slow but significantly quicker (~5 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was faulty hardware.

I Replaced motherboard with one of the same series/chipset (so did not require an install) now the timings are returning correct on both scripts.

Comment: I'm still not sure, the motherboard had advanced settings for cpu and chipset tuning. I tried several configurations (including default settings) with no result. My best guess is that the chipset is buggy with Linux Mint as the manufacturer has release optimized chipset drivers for the board, but for Windows OS's only.